# "Українська мова" чи "українська"?

Tags: вживання-слів, вибір-слова, власні-назви

Чи потрібно додавати іменник-кваліфікатор "мова"? Чи це якось врегульовано у словниках чи інших нормативних мовознавчих документах.

Помітила на одному веб-сайті міжнародної дипломатичної установи із кількома локалізаціями, що європейські мови сайту названі одним словом (English, Deutsch, Italiano тощо), але при виборі української ця опція подана як "Українська мова".

Вікіпедія є ненадійним та надостатньо офіційним джерелом, бо в ній для різних мов формат визначень назви мови відрізняється:

- [**Українська мова**](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0) - українська
- [**idioma español** o **castellano**](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idioma_espa%C3%B1ol) - іспанська, замість "español"
- [Die **deutsche Sprache** bzw. **Deutsch**](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deutsche_Sprache) - німецька, Deutsch
- [**English**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_language) -англійська мова, English (при цьому назва статті є "English Language")

Але окрім неї не маю гадки, куди й дивитися.

Comment: Цьікаве питанье — чи десь врегульоване назва нашоьі мови. А особисто — можна сміливо вживати при виборі _Украьинська_, оскільки сенс зрозумілиь. Сье стосуье і до инших, наприклад слово _English_ ье прьамим відповідним прикметником до нашого, сьебто _English cuisine_ ~ _Украьинська кухньа_.

Answer (score 4):

Мені здається, що приставка `мова` не є обов'язковою.

Це (неявно) підтверджується наступним:

1. Google видає більше підказок без `мова`: `говоріть українською`, `скільки людей говорить українською` тощо.
2. Google, Microsoft та інші ресурси в налаштуваннях мови вживають саме варіант `Українська (Україна)`.

Також в деяких випадках зустрічав написання з вибором між `English, Espanol, На русском, Українською`.

Тому вважаю вірним варіант `українська`, а слово `мова` - контекстним.

Comment: Здебільшого згоден, але я б сказав, _підказки_ в гуглі — то такий собі показник… Хтозна, за яким алгоритмом вони генерують їх. Може, наприклад, показують довший варіант лише тоді, коли він _на порядки_ переважає коротший. Я б радше порахував саме результати — або в тому ж гуглі, або в ГРАК (говорити — [664](http://www.parasolcorpus.org/bonito/run.cgi/first?corpname=grac10&queryselector=cqlrow&cql=[lemma="говорити"]+"українською"+[word!="мовою"]) проти [406](http://www.parasolcorpus.org/bonito/run.cgi/first?corpname=grac10&queryselector=cqlrow&cql=[lemma="говорити"]+"українською"+"мовою")…

Comment: …говорити/розмовляти/балакати — [1427](http://www.parasolcorpus.org/bonito/run.cgi/first?corpname=grac10&queryselector=cqlrow&cql=[lemma="говорити|розмовляти|балакати"]+"українською"+[word!="мовою"]) проти [794](http://www.parasolcorpus.org/bonito/run.cgi/first?corpname=grac10&queryselector=cqlrow&cql=[lemma="говорити|розмовляти|балакати"]+"українською"+"мовою")).

Comment: Google - це не джерело.

Answer (score 0):

### Українська мова

Відповідно до статті 10 (Розділ І — «Загальні засади») Конституції України, українська мова є єдиною державною мовою України.

> **Стаття 10**. Державною мовою в Україні є українська мова.
>
> Держава забезпечує всебічний розвиток і функціонування української
> мови в усіх сферах суспільного життя на всій території України.
>
> В Україні гарантується вільний розвиток, використання і захист
> російської, інших мов національних меншин України.
>
> Держава сприяє вивченню мов міжнародного спілкування.
>
> Застосування мов в Україні [гарантується Конституцією України](https://www.president.gov.ua/ua/documents/constitution/konstituciya-ukrayini-rozdil-i#:%7E:text=%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%82%D1%8F%2010.,%D1%96%D0%BD%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%85%20%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%86%D1%96%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%85%20%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%BD%20%D0%A3%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D0%B8.) та
> [визначається законом](https://zakon.rada.gov.ua/laws/show/2704-19#Text).

Норми української мови встановлюються у словниках української мови й [українському правописі](https://mon.gov.ua/ua/osvita/zagalna-serednya-osvita/navchalni-programi/ukrayinskij-pravopis-2019).

### Українська

У складнопідрядних реченнях, коли в першій частині речення визначено що йдеться саме про мову, у підрядній частині можна вжити простий іменник "українська". Також не потрібно вживати кваліфікатор "мова", якщо "українська" зустрічається серед переліку інших мов.